# How do I resolve a "low space" error when upgrading?

Tags: upgrade

I tried to update via the "update manager", but when I click on the update button it gives a low space error. I tried running `sudo apt-get clean` in a terminal but that also ends in vain.

How can I clean up enough space to update?

I am confused in which disk is Ubuntu installed and I don't know which disk I have to empty. I have a compaq CPU with a 1 gb ram and 250 gb hard disk and I currently dual boot my pc with windows 7 and ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Type the following command into a terminal and then post the output here sudo df -h It will tell you your available free space on the drive

Comment: Do you know what your partition structure is? Do you have boot / and home in different partitions?  I'm just wondering if one particular partition is short of space.

Comment: that wont matter, he has a folder with enough space and if he uses the live cd/usb it will work. Have you tried it Yash ?

Answer (score 1):

You can see how much free space is available to Ubuntu with `df -h` as Mark Rooney suggests. If you're really not sure what is taking up space, try running the Disk Usage Analyzer (under Accessories in your Gnome menu) which will give you a graphical overview of what is taking up space.

You also have a Disk Utility in your System > Administration menu which you may be able to use to expand or reduce the size of your various partitions.

Comment: `sudo` is not necessary for checking the filesystem size. Please do not use `sudo` as the default prefix for programs, otherwise you get used on using it, even on `sudo malicious-command`.

Comment: Definitely: you should always look up a command to understand what it does, especially if you're going to run it as root `yelp man:df` will launch `df`'s man page. However, I do get `Permission denied errors` on some directories when I run `df` without sudo.

Comment: Have you mounted a network share as root? If I run `sudo df -h`, I'm missing filesystems mounted using `sshfs`.

Comment: This is getting way, way off topic. We agree that `sudo` is not a default command prefix.

Comment: More to the point, sudo in this case is unnecessary. We don't care about the size of potentially restricted network shares, only the local fs where Ubuntu is installed.

Answer (score 0):

remove some photos, videos or music, then make a live cd (or live usb) and install 11.04 via that.

If you go into system monitor and looks at the "system" tab how much free disk space do you have?

I would suggest you download your version 32/64 bit and upgrade your current version to 11.04 via a live cd, [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) is the download.

Comment: Hardware memory is 991mb and available disk space is 15.8 gb and i dont store my documents in home folder , I save it in different disks.By the way how much memory do we need to update ?

Comment: you have enough, I think it's about 512 to make unity work smooth.